# Ubuntu 20.04 Ubuntu software doesn't show installedsoftware

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, software-center

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur39r.png)

I'm new to Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to install few software through Ubuntu software. But it stuck in this screen and don't know how to pass this. Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors shows the mirror you've selected is *behind* (beyond what the *counter* can cope with, thus it's *unknown*) so I'd suggest using another mirror.

Comment: but why it doesn't show already installed software either, why it stuck in this window I have switced several servers no different

Comment: Your picture shows *Software & Updates* and not *Ubuntu* Software. Software & Updates is used to change mirrors, change sources being used, & more, but not to download & install packages (not user packages anyway)